# SMTP Server Needs Daily Restart - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-6, smtp

I've got a Windows Server 2008 machine that is using an SMTP server with IIS 6. (I don't know the circumstances of that setup.) The machine itself uses IIS 7.

It quits working after like a day. I have to reboot the service daily just to get it to keep working.

I'm actually a UNIX guy, so I don't even know where to begin looking for where the failure is. Alternatively, does anyone have a solution? (The SMTP service sends out emails from websites.)

Comment: "It quits working after like a day" doesn't tell us anything about the nature of the problem. What about it quits working?

Comment: In addition to joe's comment... what do the logs say?

Comment: The logs say nothing in particular. As far as I can tell, SMTP logs don't throw errors or anything (or, there are no errors here).

Comment: in addition to the smtp server logs,  you need to look in the Windows event viewer at the application and system logs to see what was happening at the time the smtp  service stopped.

Comment: also,  the smtp service is an iis6  relic so that is normal.

Comment: When you say "quits working", do you mean the service is stopped? or that it just isn't accepting connections? do you have logging enabled? have you looked at the log, what is the last entry?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, create a batch file and enter the following:

```
@echo off
net stop smtpsvc
net start smtpsvc
```

Then create a scheduled task to run it once a day or however often you deem necessary.